# Error message when deploy from QA to Production

Tags: deployment, api-version

I tried to deploy a flow from Dev to QA everything works fine but when i tried to deploy it from QA to Production I got this error message, can anyone please help me to resolve it?
[image]

Comment: You've made updates on a preview of Spring '24. Production orgs are yet to be migrated to that version, hence the error. You'll have to change the flow's API version or wait for your production org to be migrated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to downgrade the API version of your flow from `60.0` to `59.0`, you production is still on the previous api version and has not been migrated yet, to do so, in the Setup of your QA org:

1. Go to `Flows` > `Flows`.
2. Click the flow `Opportunity_SAC_Sync_Status_Updated` to open the details panel.
3. In `Details`, select the version `59.0` in the drop down menu.
4. Click on `Submit`.